# Has my coconut yoghurt spoiled?

Tags: fermentation, yogurt, spoilage

I've made some coconut yoghurt from powdered coconut milk, tapioca flour, maple syrup and a spoonful of store-bought yoghurt. The mixture (apart from the old yoghurt) was simmered for a while, and the utensils had boiling water run over them from the kettle - except, come to think of it, the spoon used for the old yoghurt.

I left it for 24h in an incubator. It has a good consistency, but it has a pinkish patch and some yellow on top. The pink patch has a slight stringyness to it. I removed that part and gave it a stir and now it looks great, but I'm suspicious of it.

[image: photo of discoloured coconut yoghurt in bowl]

Has it spoiled?

Comment: I'm not making this an answer because I know nothing about trying to make lactobaccillus grow in coconut milk, but [this website](https://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-dairyfree-coconut-yogurt-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-216358) which seems to use largely the same recipe/method you describe, specifically says 'If the yogurt develops a pink or grey discoloration on its surface, that means it has been contaminated with bad bacteria. Throw it away and do not eat it!'.